# Choosing an appropriate model - What does this phrase mean?

Tags: model-selection, model

I have a question where I am given a short story:

> An investigator wishes to evaluate the effect of medicine administered
>   for colds on reaction time. Data represent the reaction times (in
>   seconds) on a stimulus one hour after each of four randomly chosen
>   brands of this type of medicine was administered to 5 people.

They then ask me to:

*Give an appropriate model*

After spending some time searching for what this means, I am mostly getting results for "choosing the right test".

What I am thinking of choosing is between:

- Analysis of Variance
- Covariance Analysis
- Regression Analysis

Can these be considered "models" or is a "model" defined as something else (in statistical terms) ?

Comment: Anything with the word "analysis" in it can't be a model, by definition. The goal is to "explain" reaction time by each of the medications. The goal of the model is to answer such questions like, "what brand had the longest/shortest reaction time?" Presumably, the idea is to figure out what brand is most effective in treating cold symptoms.

Comment: What type of models will I then be looking at? You don't have to provide any answer, but can you please reference different models that you are aware of?

Comment: The type of model you should be using depend on what "reaction time" actually means. If the experiment just involved waiting one hour, not all of the medications may have reacted. From your description what you should be measuring is time to reaction, i.e. how long do you have to wait for reaction. "Time to event" models are their own special breed and differ very much from the others. If you're reading an introductory undergrad book, chances are they're not looking for that. 1/2

Comment: 2/2 They are probably looking for a simple categorical regression model of the form: 
reaction time = intercept + coefficient*Brand1+ coefficient*Brand2, etc. Under this framework, if the brand didn't cause a reaction within the 1 hour time frame, it's just counted as not having reacted at all. Realistically, the brand in question may react, but it takes longer than an hour.

Comment: Okay, your second part is beginning to give me more clarity now. From wanting to know what "model", I actually need to try to model the data in terms of variables. Thanks.

Comment: Of course you need variables! What else can you build a model out of, other than variables? I'm assuming that you have some kind of data set that looks like this:
Person1: reaction time: 20 min; brand1;
Person2: reaction time: 45 min.;brand5; and so on for all subjects.

Comment: rocinate: no, that is all the information they provided for that question.